# How to upload a file to a Node Js Server

Tags: android, node.js, file, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to a Node.js server, but to no success.

I have  tried this for days and I am willing to accept anything; a fix suggestion of my approach so far, or even a totally different tried approach that works.

With my code I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined` on the **Node** side and I only get the `onFailure` called, and never the `onSuccess`.

The following is what I have so far:

**Java side**

```
public void upload(final String filePath) {

    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams requestParams = prepareRequestParams(filePath);

    asyncHttpClient.post(LOCALHOST_FILE_UPLOAD_URL, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            Log.v("MyApp", "SUCCESS");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("MyApp", "FAIL");

        }
    });

}

private RequestParams prepareRequestParams(String filePath) {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    try {
        requestParams.put("image", inputStream, "image", new File(filePath).toURL().openConnection().getContentType());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return requestParams;
}
```

**Node side**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'rev_uploads/')

        console.log('file.fieldname : ' + file.fieldname)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res) {

    console.log('file.fieldname : ' + req.image.filename)

    res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

Why am I getting fails with this.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: is the `upload.single('image')`  the image name is same as the name property of you `input type file ` html tag?

Comment: It is `image` @VaibhavKumarGoyal

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('file.fieldname : ' + req.image.filename);
```

replace to

```
console.log(req);
```

And look what you have inside of query. Node stop throws error and must return 200.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry for bad English

req.image looks undefined.

I think, if Multer used, there will be req.file.image.filename

```
req.image => req.file.image // check req.file or req.files I confused.
```

IN ADDITION,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

These type of error really easy to find in js.

> These means foo.bar.undefined.filename

Just find where it used. (in case filename)